403 Forbidden error on my page after creating a storage link with php artisan
since I've created a storage link, I am encoutering a 403 error on a page. Not all pages.
I want to create a projects page, and retrieve my project (name, description, img) from the database. Since I created a storage link I got a 403 error on my projects page.
pages/projects.blade.php
@extends('components.layout')

@section('content')
    @foreach ($projects as $project)
        <section class="h-full" style="height:100vh">
            <div>
                <img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $project->image_path) }}" alt="{{ $project->name }}" class="w-full h-full object-cover">

            </div>
            <div class="flex items-center justify-center h-full">
                <h1 class="uppercase text-6xl font-antonio font-bold text-title">{{ $project->name }}</h1>
                <p class="font-antonio text-text">{{ $project->description }}</p>
            </div>
    @endforeach
@endsection

Projectcontroller.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Project;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $projects = Project::all();
        return view('pages/projects', compact('projects'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('CRUD.Create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Valideer de ingevoerde gegevens, inclusief de afbeelding
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'description' => 'required|string',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048', // Max 2MB en alleen afbeeldingen
        ]);
    
        // Sla de afbeelding op in de 'public/projects' map
        $path = $request->file('image')->store('projects', 'public');
    
        // Maak een nieuw project aan met de naam, beschrijving en afbeelding
        $project = new Project();
        $project->name = $request->input('name');
        $project->description = $request->input('description');
        $project->image_path = $path;  // Sla het afbeeldingspad op in de database
        $project->save();
    
        // Redirect naar een gewenste route, bijvoorbeeld de index-pagina
        return redirect()->route('projects.index')->with('success', 'Project successfully created!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show(Project $project)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     */
    public function edit(Project $project)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Project $project)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy(Project $project)
    {
        //
    }
}


any error in storage/logs/laravel.log ? also try setting the permission to sudo chmod -R 775 storage and
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage

The problem wasn't the permissions.
I already had created a projects map, so Laravel couldn't create on itself.
So, if you are linking a storage, do not create a map yourself.
I didn't knew it would be done automatic.
